# Call Spring bean method in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a java class

LayoutManager.java, which I pass as a Sprean Bean into my jsp page using

```
 <custom:useSpringBean var="layoutManager" bean="LayoutManager"/>
```

How do I call methods from LayoutManager.java inside my jsp using the spring bean?

I feel like I would use some form of servlets <% %>, but not sure about the syntax

I want to call the method

```
 public Iterable<Layouts> getSpecificLayout(String subjectName)
```

The only spring code I have right now is

```
 public class UseSpringBean extends SimpleTagSupport
 {
     public void doTag() throws JspException, IOExceptionP
        PageContext pageContext = (PageContext)getJspContext();
        WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext());
        pageContext.setAttribute(var, springContext.getBean(bean), PageContxt.PAGE_SCOPE);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the list of `Layouts` to be used in the jsp page then from the spring controller you need to add this list in the `ModelMap` so that its visible in the jsp page.

Something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getSpecificLayout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSpecificLayout(Stirng subjectName, ModelMap model){
    Iterable<Layouts> layouts = getSpecificLayout(String subjectName);
    model.addAttribute("layouts", layouts);
    return "listLayouts";
}
```

in jsp:

```
<c:for items="listLayouts" var="layout">
  <c:out value="layout.name"/>
</c:for>
```

(This is not a tested code just a sample. Sorry somehow the code editing is not working, I mean I am not able to see the inline editor).

Comment: Is there now way for me to just call the function straight up in the JSP page using servlets? I'm pass in the subjectName using a JSP search form, and I want the method to just run that

Comment: one way which i can think of add as attribute in the http request/response in the servlet and access that using the jsp's in built request/response objects. Check out this link for more info http://www.gulland.com/courses/jsp/objects